# Get Value of ItemData in Repeater into Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Repeater nested in another Repeater. For clarity, we'll refer to them as `ParentRepeater` and `ChildRepeater`. I need to get a value from `ParentRepeater` in `ChildRepeater`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child repeater item the first NamingContainer is the Repeater and the second the parent Repetaer item.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer).DataItem, "Name") %>
```

Comment: I Need to use using System.ComponentModel ? in this case?

Comment: @RodrigoAlves `<%# DataBinder.Eval((DirectCast(Container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem).DataItem, "Name") %>`